# Photo doesn't have a date and location when capturing in-app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an app that lets the user pick a photo from his gallery and uses its location and capturing date after it.

The user also have an option to capture the photo inside the app using the camera, after the user takes the pic it adds to the gallery and then he can choose it from the gallery.

The problem is that when the pic was taken inside the app, the location and capturing date aren't being saved, and I have no idea why.

Anyone knows why is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For that use class - PHAsset,  creationDate - for date, location - for location, look PHAsset class for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you have finished chosen picture from gallery  method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` fetches  all the appropriate information about that picture.

Delegate method `info` parameter contains relevant information about picture you can get by parsing dict `keys` after see below code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
        // do something with the metadata

    NSLog(@"meta : %@ \n\n",metadataDictionary);
}
```

You will get `DateTime` key contains capture date and time and so on..

Comment: But the problem is that it doesn't save it on the camera roll with this info